# Parse XML using Google Apps Script to create google sheet

Tags: xml, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've spent over 10 hours searching for answers and trying out on google scripts, but I'm stuck.
Given this sample xml script: https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC3/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.demandware.dochelp%2Fcontent%2Fb2c_commerce%2Ftopics%2Fimport_export%2Fb2c_inventory_list_object_import_export.html

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<inventory xmlns="http://www.demandware.com/xml/impex/inventory/2007-05-31"> #Specifies the inventory.xsd file that defines the schema.
    <inventory-list>
        <records>
            <record product-id="ProductWithAllocation"> #Sets the stock level at 10 for product "ProductWithAllocation".
                <allocation>10</allocation>
                <perpetual>false</perpetual>
            </record>
            <record product-id="ProductWithBackorderAllocation"> #Sets stock level and backorder allocation to 10 for product "ProductWithBackorderAllocation".
                <allocation>10</allocation>
                <perpetual>false</perpetual>
                <preorder-backorder-handling>backorder</preorder-backorder-handling>
                <preorder-backorder-allocation>10</preorder-backorder-allocation>
            </record>
            <record product-id="ProductWithPerpetualFlag">
                <perpetual>true</perpetual>
            </record>
        </records>
    </inventory-list>
```

How do I convert this XML into a google sheet table using Google script?

Thanks!

Comment: About `How do I convert this XML into a google sheet table using Google script?`, can you provide the output situation you expect?

Comment: Have you tried `=IMPORTXML(...)` with appropriate XPath?

Comment: The extract is not complete, you have to close the xml by `</inventory>` then use importxml

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use `local-name()` in your xpath (after completing the xml file with `</inventory>`)

Try

```
=importxml(url,"//*")
```

or

```
=IMPORTXML(url,"//*[local-name() ='record']")
```

[image]